# SecChrootDir Jailing apache 2.2.X on Centos 6.7

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, chroot, mod-security

I was trying to do apache jailing on centos 6.7 with modsec. I already built everything even the jail directory and remodeled the config files. httpd(apache) says it started nicely, however its dead. When i try to see its status it says httpd dead but subsys locked.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that httpd is stopped

```
service httpd stop
```

Remove any stale lock files

```
rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
```

Ensure there are no httpd processes running

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

if there are kill them

```
pkill httpd
```

Now start httpd

```
service start httpd
```